# Passing a Hash Map to a Function - Java

Tags: java, hashmap

Code:

```
public void saveFile(HashMap hashTable) {

    for (Employee e : hashTable.values()) {
            //...
    }
}
```

When I try to run this code, I receive the following error:

```
 incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to Employee 
           for (Employee e : hashTable.values()) {
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You used the raw form of `HashMap`, so `hashTable.values()` returns a raw `Collection`, which returns `Object`s, which can't be assigned directly to an `Employee` variable.

Use the generic form of `HashMap`, either:

```
public void saveFile(HashMap<?, Employee> hashTable) {
```

or

```
public void saveFile(HashMap<YourKey, Employee> hashTable) {
```

Then `values()` will return a `Collection<Employee>`, out of which you can extract `Employee`s.

Or you might even use the `Map` interface, coding to the interface:

```
public void saveFile(Map<YourKey, Employee> hashTable) {
```

Answer (score 0):

If the value of the map should be Employee, change the signature to :

```
public void saveFile(Map<TheKeyType,Employee> hashTable) {
```

where TheKeyType should be replaced with the type of your key (which is likely to be String or Integer).

when you use the raw Map type, `hashTable.values()` will return a raw `Collection`, so iterating over it will give you `Object` references, not `Employee` references.